# Find basis of $X = \{\cos^i(x) \cdot \sin^j(x) | i, j \geq 0, i + j \leq 3\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

In space of continuous functions $\{f: [0, 2 \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \}$ let's consider set of vectors $X = \{\cos^i(x) \cdot \sin^j(x) | i, j \geq 0, i + j \leq 3\}$. Find maximal linearly independent system of vectors (basis) and express all other vectors form set $X$ using that system.

To be honest, I am not sure what to do here. For instance, If I were to choose basis $1, \sin x, \cos x, \cos^2x$ I do not see here any way to express $\sin^3x$ or $\cos^3x$. Means that we have to add them to our combination (it is obvious that we do not add here $\sin^2x$ here because it is expressed using linerar combination of 1 and $\cos^2x$).

But what would be nice and formal way to choose basis here? I mean with explanation that it is actually basis.

Comment: Where do you use $j$? I see all $i$ in the expression

Comment: @Andrei Edited.

Comment: Hint: $\sin^3(x) = \sin x - \cos^2 x \sin x$ and similarly, using $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$, you can express each element of $X$ as a linear combination of the subset where in addition $j \le 1$.